# Epoch to timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' while redshift copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to format the epoch to  timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' while
doing redshift copy from s3 to redshift using COPY command

Comment: The format is used to parse incoming data. Redshift keeps timestamp as internal data type.

Answer (score 9):

You can use redshift COPY command with parameter `TIMEFORMAT 'epochsecs'`
or `TIMEFORMAT 'epochmillisecs'`
Check [redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) documentation for more details

Answer (score 1):

Sample COPY query using javascript miliseconds (13 digits): [Possible options in documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-timeformat)

```
COPY "hits" FROM 's3://your-bucket/your_folder/'
      CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>;aws_secret_access_key=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
      FORMAT as JSON 's3://your-bucket/config/jsonpaths'
      TIMEFORMAT as 'epochmillisecs';
```