# Epoch timestamp to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' format conversion while executing AWS Redshift COPY command

Tags: amazon-redshift

With ref to other related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496065/epoch-to-timeformat-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmiss-while-redshift-copy); with following configuration I able to insert data into Redshift -

```
COPY "hits" FROM 's3://your-bucket/your_folder/'
  CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>;aws_secret_access_key=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
  FORMAT as JSON 's3://your-bucket/config/jsonpaths'
  TIMEFORMAT as 'epochmillisecs';
```

It is converting '1528207694599' into '2018-06-05 14:08:14' , but I'm expecting '2018-06-05 14:08:14.599' .

Any luck? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may be doing something wrong at somewhere, I would like to show you a systamatic steps, to prove copy populates data properly including milliseconds.

```
create table sales(
salesid integer not null,
category varchar(10),
update_at timestamp);
```

data file data.json's content

```
[1,"Sports1","1528207694599"]
[2,"Sports2","1528207694456"]
```

Mapping file json_path.json's content

```
{
"jsonpaths": [
    "$[0]",
    "$[1]",
    "$[2]"
]
}
```

Then copy command,

```
COPY sales FROM 's3://s3-path/to/data/data.json'  CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=**********;aws_secret_access_key=*******'   FORMAT as JSON 's3://s3-path/to/mapping/json_path.json'   TIMEFORMAT as 'epochmillisecs';

Output:
COPY sales FROM .............
INFO:  Load into table 'sales' completed, 2 record(s) loaded successfully.
COPY;

$Select * from Sales;

 salesid | category |        update_at
 ---------+----------+-------------------------
   2 | Sports2  | 2018-06-05 14:08:14.456
   1 | Sports1  | 2018-06-05 14:08:14.599
 (2 rows)
```

As you could see, `update_at` has value including milliseconds.
Hope it helps.